# How to Construct JSON from JPATH

Tags: python, json

I am working on parsing a text file having list of json paths from which I want to construct JSON.

This is how I am started.

```
def construct_json(jpath):
    tokens = jpath.strip().split('.')
    json = ''
    for token in tokens:
        if len(token.split('=')) == 2:
            json = json + '"' + token.split('=')[0] +'"' + ':' + '"' + token.split('=')[1] + '"}}}}'
        else:
            json = json + '"'+token+'":{'
    return '{'+json

jpaths_text = 'quiz.sport.q1.question=Which one is correct team name in NBA?,quiz.sport.q1.question=Which one is correct team name in Soccer?'
jpaths = jpaths_text.split(',')

questions = []
for jpath in jpaths:
    questions.append(construct_json(jpath))

print questions
```

Above program gives me following output:

```
['{"quiz":{"sport":{"q1":{"question":"Which one is correct team name in NBA?"}}}}', '{"quiz":{"sport":{"q1":{"question":"Which one is correct team name in Soccer?"}}}}']
```

What I want is all `q1` in list. something like following:

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": [{
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?"
            }, {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in Soccer?"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/clue will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Will the path `quiz.sport.q1.question` always be the same for every one?

Comment: Yes it will remain same always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import json


def extract_questions(jpaths_text):
    questions_path = 'quiz.sport.q1.question='
    questions = {
        'quiz': {
            'sport': {
                'q1': [],
            },
        },
    }
    for jpath in jpaths_text.split(','):
        if jpath.find(questions_path) == 0:
            questions['quiz']['sport']['q1'].append(
                jpath.replace(questions_path, ''))
    return questions


jpaths_text = 'quiz.sport.q1.question=Which one is correct team name in NBA?,quiz.sport.q1.question=Which one is correct team name in Soccer?'
questions = extract_questions(jpaths_text)
questions_json = json.dumps(questions)
print(questions_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

well if the structure will be the same structure as that Example then you can use something like this:

```
ls = ['{"quiz":{"sport":{"q1":{"question":"Which one is correct team name in NBA?"}}}}',
      '{"quiz":{"sport":{"q1":{"question":"Which one is correct team name in Soccer?"}}}}']

d = {"quiz": {
    "sport": {
        "q1": []
    }

}}
for dic in ls:
    q1 = json.loads(dic).get('quiz').get('sport').get("q1")
    d.get('quiz').get('sport').get('q1').append(q1)

print(d)
```